# Pycharm and matplotlib working only in debug mode

Tags: python, debugging, matplotlib, pycharm

I am having a weird problem in Pycharm 2017.3.3 Community Edition. I am making a cycle that is supposed to show different figures in each iteration. When I run the code, only the first figure shows and the program gets stuck. The same happens if I run the code in debug mode with no breakpoints. However, if I set a breakpoint, and keep resuming the program when it reaches the breakpoint, all the figures are shown and the program finishes the execution successfully. Also wanted to clarify that I have used the code before with less figures and it had worked out fine.

Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.externals import joblib

feat_file = 'C:\\Users\\DianaCarolina\\Google Drive\\Maestría\\datos\\indices_Diana\\all_type.xlsx'
sites = {"Bosque":['5256', '5260'], "Rastrojo": ['5253', '5255'], "Pastizal": ['5257', '7125']}
model=joblib.load("C:\\Users\\DianaCarolina\\Google Drive\\Maestría\\datos\\indices_Diana\\ecotyhmm13_3.pkl")
nclasses = 13
for comp in range(nclasses):
    histData = []
    types = []
    col = []
    for type in sites:
        df = pd.read_excel(feat_file, sheet_name=type, index_col=0)
        mdata=df.loc[df.iloc[:, 20] == comp, "Mes"]
        types.append(type)
        histData.append(mdata)

        if len(col) < 3:
            if type == "Bosque" and "green" not in col:
                col.append("green")
            elif type == "Rastrojo" and "orange" not in col:
                col.append("orange")
            elif type == "Pastizal" and "yellow" not in col:
                col.append("yellow")

    mclass = np.sum(np.array([model.gmms_[comp].weights_]).T * model.gmms_[comp].means_, 0)

    plt.figure()

    if not histData[0].empty or not histData[1].empty or not histData[2].empty:
        plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
        n, bins, patches = plt.hist(histData, np.arange(0.5,13, 1), stacked=True, label= types, color = col, rwidth=0.8)
        plt.legend()
        plt.xticks(range(1,13), ("Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", \
                                      "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"))
        plt.title("Clase "+str(comp+1)+" de "+str(nclasses))

        plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)

    plt.stem(mclass)
    plt.xticks(range(14), list(df.loc[:, "M":"Salida2_4"]))
    plt.title("Medias de características para la clase")
    plt.show()
```

Comment: To help you out we would need https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: How much times about your cycle statement?

Comment: @FrankAK it should show 13 figures.

Comment: Can you put your screenshots here?

Comment: @sophros ok I will work on it :)

Comment: @FrankAK what exactly should the screenshots show?

Comment: Can you post the code that you have?

Comment: @DavidG ok, is a little long though

Comment: If your code is very long, trim it down to a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as this is the best way to get the good answers

Comment: Unindent `plt.show()` and you will get multiple figures

Comment: @DavidG thank you, it worked :) makes me wonder though, why it worked before with less figures with plt.show() indented. Now, this is my first question, how do I reward you?

Comment: I have added my comment as an answer below. If any answer solves your problem then you may [accept/upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it to mark it as solved. However, it is up to you to decide which answer is the best/which works for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`plt.show()` should usually only be called once at the end of your code. This will show all figures that have been created and it will *block* the execution of any code after it.

E.g.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i in range(2):
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot([1,2,3])

    plt.show()
```

This will only show the second figure *after* you close the first one.

The simplest solution would be to un-indent your `plt.show()` such that once all the figures have been created they will all be shown.